# How to deploy Angular 2 with grunt?

Tags: angular, web, npm, gruntjs

I am trying to build an Angular2 app and I want to use Grunt to deploy it. For some reason, when I run the deployed index.html my code doesn't work. The code in question is the example from the angular website. I assume I'm either missing a dependency or soemthing is not deployed correctly.

Also when running "grunt" from the terminal I'm getting the error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked on the "deploy" folder. How could I get it to work? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
Syn.

I installed the dependencies using npm install with the following **package.json** file:

```
{
   "name": "MyProject",
   "version": "0.0.1",
   "description": "My description",
   "main": "index.html",
   "scripts": {
       "postinstall": "npm dedupe"
   },
   "author": "Me",
   "license": "UNLICENSED",
   "dependencies": {
       "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.5",
       "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.5",
       "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.5",
       "@angular/forms": "0.3.0",
       "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.5",
       "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.5",
       "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.5",
       "@angular/router-deprecated": "2.0.0-rc.0",
       "@angular/upgrade": "2.0.0-rc.0",
       "systemjs": "0.19.27",
       "es6-shim": "^0.35.0",
       "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
       "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
       "zone.js": "^0.6.12",
       "angular2-in-memory-web-api": "0.0.5",
       "bootstrap": "^3.3.6"
   },
   "devDependencies": {
       "@types/core-js": "^0.9.37",
       "babel-cli": "^6.18.0",
       "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.16.0",
       "babel-runtime": "^6.11.6",
       "concurrently": "^2.0.0",
       "grunt": "^1.0.1",
       "grunt-babel": "^6.0.0",
       "grunt-contrib-clean": "^1.0.0",
       "grunt-contrib-concat": "^1.0.1",
       "grunt-contrib-copy": "^1.0.0",
       "grunt-contrib-less": "^1.4.1",
       "grunt-contrib-sass": "^1.0.0",
       "grunt-contrib-uglify": "^2.0.0",
       "grunt-contrib-watch": "^1.0.0",
       "grunt-sync": "^0.6.2",
       "lite-server": "^2.2.0",
       "typescript": "^1.8.10",
       "typings": "^0.8.1"
   }, "repository": {
       "type": "git",
       "url": "ssh://< MY REPO>"
   }
}
```

My **tsconfig.json** looks like this:

```
{ "compilerOptions": {
    "declaration": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "mapRoot": "./",
    "module": "es6",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "outDir": "../deploy",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es6"
}}
```

And my **gruntfile.js** like this:

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
            clean: {
            src: ['deploy/**']
        }, concat: {
            options: {
                separator: ';'
            }, dist: {
                src: ['src/js/**/*.js'],
                dest: 'deploy/js/<%= pkg.name %>.concat.js'
            } 
        }, babel: {
            options: {
                presets: ["es2015"],
                sourceMap: true,
                compact: true,
                babelrc: false
            }, files: {
                expand: true,
                src: ['<%= concat.dist.dest %>'],
                ext: '-babel.js'
            }
        }, typescript: {
            base: {
                src: [
                    'js/tsd.d.ts',
                    'js/*.ts',
                    'app.ts',
                    'app.js',
                    'js/*.js'
                ], dest:'build',
                options: {
                    target:'ES6',
                    module:'commonjs',
                    sourceMap:true,
                    watch: {
                        after: ['copy'],
                        atBegin: true
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        uglify: {
            options: {
                preserveComments: false,
                screwIE8: true,
                banner: '/*! <%= pkg.name %> <%= grunt.template.today("dd-mm-yyyy") %> */\n'
            }, default: {
                options: {mangle: true},
                files: {
                    'deploy/js/<%= pkg.name %>.min.js': ['temp/<%= pkg.name %><%=babel.files.ext %>']
                }
            }, dev: {
                options: {mangle: false, beautify: true},
                files: {
                    'deploy/js/<%= pkg.name %>.min.js': ['temp/<%= pkg.name %><%=babel.files.ext %>']
                }
            }
        }, sync: {
            main: {
                files: [{
                    cwd: 'src',
                    src: ['**', '!**/*.js', '!**/*.scss'],
                    dest: 'deploy'
                }, {
                    cwd: 'node_modules/@angular',
                    src: ['angular.min.js'],
                    dest: 'deploy/js'
                }, {
                    cwd: 'node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js',
                    src: ['bootstrap.min.js'],
                    dest: 'deploy/js'
                }, {
                    cwd: 'src',
                    src: ['**/*.html'],
                    dest: 'deploy'
                }] 
            }
        }, watch: {
            JS: {
                files: ['src/js/**'],
                tasks: ['watcherDoJsNoUgly'],
                options: {spawn: true}
            }, CSS: {
                files: ['src/css/**'],
                tasks: ['sync'],
                options: {spawn: true}
            }, HTML_AND_OTHER_FILES: {
                files: ['src/html/*.html', 'src/res/**'],
                tasks: ['sync'],
                options: {spawn: true}
            }
        }
    });
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-babel');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-clean');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-sync');
    grunt.registerTask('watcherDoJsNoUgly', ['concat', 'babel', 'uglify:dev']);
    grunt.registerTask('watcherDoJs', ['concat', 'babel', 'uglify:default']);
    grunt.registerTask('default', ['clean', 'watcherDoJsNoUgly', 'sync', 'watch']);
    grunt.registerTask('deploy', ['clean', 'watcherDoJs', 'sync'])

};
```

And my folder structure looks like this:

[image]

Comment: I haven't seen a Grunt task myself yet for Angular 2. As such, you may need to just use a grun-shell or grun-exec plugin to call out to the Angular 2 CLI until there is one made. Or you could make one yourself too doing essentially what I just said.

Answer (score -1):

You shouldn't use Grunt, just use [Angular CLI](https://cli.angular.io/). It's maintained by the angular team and uses the webpack bundler so there is no need for Grunt.

To compile your app you would run **[`ng build`](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/build)** :

```
ng build --prod //this will also minify/uglify,...
```

Here is a more in depth article on [why you should use Angular CLI](https://ajsblackbelt.wordpress.com/2016/09/24/why-should-you-use-angular-cli/)

Comment: There may be legacy apps and use cases out there with *existing* and potentially complicated Grunt builds which cannot simply be migrated to  another build tool or tools i.e. Angular CLI - something to consider, as this doesn't really answer @Syn's question.